# How to show logical and after that xor in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, enums, xor

I am a beginner so please take it easy on me.

I wrote this code: `((x.Tags ?? 0) & byteFlags)) ^ (byteFlags) > 0)` 
x.tags is long data type 
`(long)byteFlagEnum.somethings & (long)byteFlagEnum.thing;`

there  is structure of byteFlagEnum  </br />

```
public enum HotelBookTag : long
{
    .... = 1 << 0,
    ... = 1 << 1,
    ....  = 1 << 2,
    ..... = 1 << 3,
    thing = 1 << 4,
    somethings = 1 << 5,
}
```

but it givse me this error

`Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'bool'`

Comment: You may need to add parentheses to stop c# first creating a bool out of `byteFlags > 0` and then xoring the bool with the rest of the expression eg  `(((x.Tags ?? 0) & byteFlags) ^ byteFlags) > 0`

Comment: i added parentheses in linq query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably your parentheses - causing the compiler to evaluate `byteFlags > 0` to a `bool` first before the bitwise operations. Can you try:

```cs
    (((x.Tags ?? 0) & byteFlags) ^ (byteFlags)) > 0)
```

Comment: I wrote that in upper comment  i added parentheses in linq query

Comment: Can you share your linq query?

Comment: i make mistake i so sorry

Answer (score 1):

> Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'bool'

Comparison operators like `>` have higher precedence than bitwise/logical operators. This helps for expressions like:

```
if(a == b && c > d)
```

If the logical had a higher precedence, many more parentheses would be required to get c# to do things in the right order

Your expression like

```
a ^ b > c
```

However, needs parentheses around the a^b otherwise c# will do the b>c first generating a book, which it then tries to xor with `a` (your long)